# How to compile multiple xsd files in Gradle JAXB/XJC?

Tags: ant, jaxb, gradle, schema, xjc

I'm fairly new to Gradle and I am facing some issues trying to compile multiple schema files using Gradle Ant XJC.

Using the below code, I'm able to compile 1 schema successfully. However, I'm not sure how to do the same for multiple schema files.

Any advice please?

```
//  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Task : XJC ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
final def packageName = "org.test.webservice.domain"
final def schemaFile = "misc/resources/schemas/employee-v3/wadl/employee.xsd"

configurations { provided }
project.ext.generatedSrcDir = file("$buildDir/generated-src")
dependencies {
    provided 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.2.6'
    provided 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.2.6'
}
task jaxb {
    println 'Starting JAXB XJC...'
    ext {
        packagePath = packageName.replaceAll("\\.", "/")
        srcFile = file(schemaFile)
        destDir = new File(project.ext.generatedSrcDir, packagePath)
    }

    inputs.file srcFile
    outputs.dir destDir
    project.ext.generatedSrcDir.mkdirs()
    ant.taskdef(name: 'xjc',
            classname: 'com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask',
            classpath: configurations.provided.asPath)

    doLast {
        project.ext.generatedSrcDir.mkdirs()
        ant.xjc(schema: srcFile, package: packageName,
                destdir: project.ext.generatedSrcDir)
    }

    task generateSources() {}
    sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs += project.ext.generatedSrcDir
    generateSources.dependsOn jaxb
    compileJava.dependsOn generateSources
    eclipseClasspath.dependsOn generateSources
//    ideaClasspath.dependsOn generateSources
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved it myself. Here is the working solution.

```
//  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Task : XJC ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
final def packageName = "org.test.webservice.domain"
final def schemaDir = "misc/resources/schemas/employee-sda-v3/wadl"

configurations { provided }
project.ext.generatedSrcDir = file("$buildDir/generated-src")
dependencies {
    provided 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.2.6'
    provided 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.2.6'
}
task jaxb {
    println 'Starting JAXB XJC...'
    ext {
        packagePath = packageName.replaceAll("\\.", "/")
        destDir = new File(project.ext.generatedSrcDir, packagePath)
    }

    outputs.dir destDir
    project.ext.generatedSrcDir.mkdirs()
    ant.taskdef(name: 'xjc', classname: 'com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask', classpath: configurations.provided.asPath)

    doLast {
        project.ext.generatedSrcDir.mkdirs()
        ant.xjc(package: packageName, destdir: project.ext.generatedSrcDir){
            schema(dir: ${schemaDir}, includes: "**/*.xsd")
        }
    }

    task generateSources() {}
    sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs += project.ext.generatedSrcDir
    generateSources.dependsOn jaxb
    compileJava.dependsOn generateSources
    eclipseClasspath.dependsOn generateSources
//    ideaClasspath.dependsOn generateSources
}
```

Comment: Sharing is caring, thanks for the answer. But I'm getting `Execution failed for task ':jaxb'.
> class com.sun.tools.xjc.XJC2Task doesn't support the nested "$" element.`. Any ideas?

Comment: Yup. I'm getting the same.

Comment: OK, so use the second one above to avoid the "$" issue... and instead get stuck with the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/bind/api/ErrorListener issue. :-/ This, combined with the lack of support for catalog files render's both Gradle (and consequently Groovy) pretty much useless for our purposes.  I mean sheesh. What kind of build tool doesn't even have mature and stable support for XML??

Comment: No need to wrap schemaDir with ${}. You can remove it or simple keep path as a String

Answer (score 2):

[jacobono's gradle-jaxb-plugin](https://github.com/jacobono/gradle-jaxb-plugin) compiles all schemas in the input directory.
I find this plugin more stable than Ant XJC. In my project, on some machines Ant XJC does not generate classes for no reason, although the results is successful. Maybe this is matter of configuration but IMHO even setup is easier with the plugin.

Comment: I believe jacobono's is discontinued. There's a maintained fork here: https://github.com/rackerlabs/gradle-jaxb-plugin

Answer (score 2):

Here is one more working example. I put complete version of my build.gradle file.
You can setup directory and include filter on schema inside of xjc.
if you have 'nested "$" element is not supported' error like above, then below my example will help

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

task genJaxb {
    ext.sourcesDir = "${buildDir}/generated-sources/jaxb"
    ext.classesDir = "${buildDir}/classes/jaxb"
    ext.schemaDir = "${projectDir}/src/main/resources"

    outputs.dir classesDir

    doLast() {
        project.ant {
            taskdef name: "xjc", classname: "com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask",
                    classpath: configurations.jaxb.asPath
            mkdir(dir: sourcesDir)
            mkdir(dir: classesDir)

            xjc(destdir: sourcesDir) {
                schema(dir: schemaDir, includes: "**/*.xsd")
                arg(value: "-wsdl")
                produces(dir: sourcesDir, includes: "**/*.java")
            }

            javac(destdir: classesDir, source: 1.8, target: 1.8, debug: true,
                    debugLevel: "lines,vars,source",
                    classpath: configurations.jaxb.asPath,
                    includeantruntime: "false") {
                src(path: sourcesDir)
                include(name: "**/*.java")
                include(name: "*.java")
            }

            copy(todir: classesDir) {
                fileset(dir: sourcesDir, erroronmissingdir: false) {
                    exclude(name: "**/*.java")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

jar {
    baseName = 'myProject'
    version = '0.0.1'
    from genJaxb.classesDir
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    jaxb
}

dependencies {
    compile("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3",
            "commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6",
            "commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1",
            "commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10",
            "commons-io:commons-io:2.4",
            "org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:2.2.1.RELEASE"
            )
    compile("wsdl4j:wsdl4j:1.6.1")
    jaxb("com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.2.4-1")
    compile(files(genJaxb.classesDir).builtBy(genJaxb))
    testCompile("junit:junit",
                "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.2",
                "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.2",
                )
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.11'
}
```

Comment: This works but I have a problem you don't. Mine is hanging because the URL for one of my name spaces is exactly that. ...and of course it's non-existent. The old maven variant of this build used a catalog to rewrite it. Problem is that I can't figure out where to insert this. I've tried several places already.  It's an attribute though. 
https://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.0.2/docs/xjcTask.html

Comment: Just some newbie question: Why do you specify as destinationDir some dir in build/generated-sources? Why not place the generated Java files straight into src/main/java?Is that for some reason considered bad practice?

Comment: you can change the destdir to src/main/java. The good side is seeing the generated code under the usual source path. The downside probably is setting up static code analysis to exclude the generated package. Otherwise static code analysis tools may complain tons about the generated code

Answer (score 2):

This could be the easiest solution without any external plugin.
Does it have any other impact?

```
task prepareXSD2Java{

    def xsdSourceDir = xsdPackageName.replace(".","/")

    FileTree xsdFilesTree = fileTree(dir: "$projectResourceDir/$xsdSourceDir")
    xsdFilesTree.include '*.xsd'


    doLast{
        xsdFilesTree.getFiles().each {
            File xsdFile -> 
            def xsdPackageExt = xsdFile.name.replace("-","_")
            xsdPackageExt = xsdPackageExt.take(xsdPackageExt.lastIndexOf("."))
            String xsdFileName = xsdFile.getAbsolutePath();

            exec {
                executable = "xjc"
                args = [ "-d", "$projectSourceDir", "-p", 
                       "$xsdPackageName.$xsdPackageExt", "$xsdFileName" ]
            }
        }
    }

}
```